# RXJS drag and drop onDrop/onDragOver

Tags: rxjs

I was trying to do the drag and drop by using RXJS.

Does anybody know how to do the onDrop or onDragOver properly with the RXJS?

Here is what I have tried. But not working...

```
let mouseup = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');
            let mousemove = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
            let mousedown = Observable.fromEvent(target, 'mousedown');
const drop = mousedown
                .flatMap((md) => {
                    return Observable
                        .concat(
                        [
                            mousemove.take(1).ignoreElements(),
                            mouseup.take(1)
                        ]
                        );
                });
```

Here is another try, which seems to be working. But it will fire whenever mouseup happens, not only fire after the drag.

```
const drop = mousemove
                .switchMap((mm) => mouseup.take(1));
```

Comment: I did some hackings. Got it working. But nor sure if it's the right way. Still welcome any posts or suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all your drag events, you can use this here

```
let up$   = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');
let move$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
let down$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousedown');

let drag$ = down$.switchMap(down => move$.takeUntil(up$));
```

This will emit every mousemove event which was triggered while you 'dragged'.

It's also very easy to adapt to your needs. Let's say you need the x-distance of your drag:

```
let distance$ = down$.switchMap((down: MouseEvent) => 
                          move$.map((move: MouseEvent) => (move.clientX - down.clientX))
                      .takeUntil(up$));
```

You want the same, but also support touch? No problem! Just merge your three input streams with their touch-equivalent and you are good to go.

I hope this answers your question,

Ben